# is there a way to collapse/unfold by levels in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, editor

I would like to know if there exists some way to collapse and unfold by levels in Visual Studio. I already know these keys:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>: collapse all
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>: unfold all
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>: toggle

They work, but they collapse and unfold to the maximum possible level. I want for example unfold at lvl 2, lvl 3 depth, then collapse to lvl 1, etc.

An example of this functionality exists in Notepad++ editor:

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>*n*</kbd>: collapse level *n*
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>*n*</kbd>: unfold to level *n*

If this functionality is provided by an extension, it'd be good to know the name of this extension.

Comment: Regions: so pointless. I just love the justification "it makes the code easier to read"...

Comment: @MitchWheat collapse/unfold functionality works with namespaces, classes, structs, methods, properties, etc. not only with Regions

Comment: Yep, it sure does. But I want to see the code!

Comment: ~2 years later, VS2013 and almost VS2014... and still can't seem to find something to do Notepad++ type "Collapse by Level"

Comment: There's also ctrl+m, l which collapses _everything_ right down to the namespace level.

Comment: 5 years.... and  counting... zzzz'

Answer (score 12):

It's useful to note that, if you first do Collapse All Outlining (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>), then you can expand/collapse regions **one level at a time**, for example by using the mouse or the Toggle Outlining Expansion shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>). Not as good as expanding/collapsing by *n* levels, but better than nothing.

Comment: This was really helpful. I would only use Notepad++ for this and for file comparison. One less reason to use Notepad++

Comment: This is what I am looking for

Comment: Ctrl + M, A is just what I was looking for. Strange, VS does not list it on Outlining menu.

Answer (score 11):

I have created an extension to provide "level folding" functionality for Visual Studio.
Please note, that it is still quite raw.

[image]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mwilski.CollapseLevel

Comment: Does what it is supposed to do :) Even works with regions

Answer (score 3):

VS code can control fold level by default nowadays.

fold by :
<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>  <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>7</kbd>

unfold all by : <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>

Check more in 'Keyboard shortcuts setting' (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>)

[image: Keyboard shortcuts setting]

Comment: Tag clearly indicates `visual-studio`, not `visual-studio-code`.

Answer (score 1):

For VS2010 used with cpp : [Tools > Options ... > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > Outline Statement Blocks] set at True.

It seems to do what you expect and certainly what i was looking for when i met your post.